# curl cookie not creating on success

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I'm using cUrl(PHP) to post a login request and store response in cookie file.
In my second request I'm passing cookie in header and post data to verify it.

Issue is that cookie file is not created in first succesful request results in failure for second request. Please suggest me where I'm doing wrong.

```
$cookiefile="/var/www/html/dimdim/cook.txt";
$url_log="http://my.dimdim.com/api/auth/login";
$p_log='request={"account":"bin6k","password":"password","group":"all"}';
$url_ver="http://my.dimdim.com/api/auth/verify";
$p_ver='request={"account":"bin6k","password":"password","group":"all"}';

$ch = curl_init();
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url_log);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $p_log);

ob_start();      // prevent any output
$retval=curl_exec ($ch); // execute the curl command
ob_end_clean();  // stop preventing output
curl_close ($ch);
//print_r($retval);
unset($ch);


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url_ver);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $p_log);

$buf2 = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

echo "<PRE>".htmlentities($buf2);
```

Answer (score 3):

i had the same problem use this for running in windows localhost server

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookies.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);` in there as well.

Also, there's no need to start a fresh curl instance for each request. You can reuse the same instance for multiple requests. Just set the appropriate CURLOPT (url, postfields, get, etc...) each time and curl will sort things out internally.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function the cookijar option is added:

```
function execute($toLoad) {

    if ( !preg_match( '/^http/', $toLoad ) ) {
        $toLoad = 'http://'.$toLoad;
    }
    $cookiefile = APP_PATH.'tmp/cookie.txt';
    $data = array();    
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1.6) Gecko/20091216 Fedora/3.5.6-1.fc11 Firefox/3.5.6 GTB6");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $toLoad); // The page to download
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://somesite.com/' ); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);    

    $data['data'] = curl_exec($ch);
    $data['status'] = curl_getinfo($ch);

    //$this->out(curl_error($ch));   
    //$this->out(curl_getinfo($ch));     
    //$this->out('');
    //$this->out($data);
    //$this->out('');

    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
```

you could also try reading the header of the returned data for  Set-Cookie: SOMEKEY

and then in the curlopt use

```
if ($header) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Cookie:'.$header)); 
}
```

Thanks